# Override form field #value after ajax request sets it

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

First of all, here is the code:

```
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form['join_newsletter'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => $this->t('Join newsletter'),
      '#default_value' => '0',
      '#weight' => '0',
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::mailCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'mail-wrapper',
      ],
    ];

    $form['container'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#attributes' => ['id' => 'mail-wrapper'],
    ];

    if (!empty($form_state->getValue('join_newsletter'))) {
      $form['container']['e_mail'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => $this->t('E-mail'),
        '#maxlength' => 64,
        '#size' => 64,
        '#weight' => '1',
        '#prefix' => '<div id="mail-wrapper">',
        '#suffix' => '</div>',
        '#value' => 'info@domain.com',
      ];
    }

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * Ajax callback.
   */
  public static function mailCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['container'];
  }
```

And here is the scenario.

The form by default shows only the `join_newsletter` checkbox. When checkbox is checked `$form['container']['e_mail']` field is rendered by ajax. Notice, I'm providing a `info@domain.com` default value represented by `#value` key for `$form['container']['e_mail']` field on ajax request.

Once the e-mail field is rendered I'd like to change this value manually on the page by deleting `info@domain.com` and typing in anything else like `info@gmail.com`. But when I submit a form `$form_state` value is always set to `info@domain.com`. It's never overriden.

Now, I'm aware I could use a `#default_value` key, but that's not the point, becasue the above code is just a simple example of what I'm facing at in my project. I tried several different solutions but none worked. Any help?

Comment: This is not a default value, this is use-case for HTML's `placeholder` attribute: e.g. `<input type="email" placeholder="info@domain.com">`

Comment: No, placeholder will not work in my case. As said, it's a simple example, but there's a bigger picture I'm dealing with. I need to override #value somehow.